# How to show text in an specific order from an array

Tags: jquery

I have an html page split in two sections (left + right) where I need to show two words per time from a list (one per section), in a defined order. **Right now I can only show them randomly like this:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var quotes = new Array("pizza", "cake", "coke");
var randno = Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length));
$('.cosa1').append(quotes[randno]);
console.log(randno);

var quotes = new Array("burger", "muffin", "pepsi");
var randno = Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length));
$('.cosa2').append(quotes[randno]);
console.log(randno);
});
```

**I am trying to show pizza with burger, cake with muffin, coke with pepsi and so on.**

My Html looks like this:

```
<div class="main-container">
<div class="left-container">
  <div>
    <h1 class="cosa1"></h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right-container">
  <div>
    <h1 class="cosa2"></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random number is declared inside of the each, which will has the potential to cause 2 different numbers, making it difficult to match. It's best to determine the random number before the `each`.

To keep the matches, the 2 arrays can be used of course, but then you have to determine the array based on the index. In the example below I've merged the 2 arrays (can also be done with an array of objects instead).

This way `quotes[randno]` returns a random array and quotes[randno]`[i]` returns the word inside the subarray.

```js
$( function(){//causes the code to be executed on document load, otherwise the 'cosa' elements won't be found (since your code is executed in the header portion of your site)
var quotes = [["pizza","burger"], ["cake","muffin"], ["coke","pepsi"]];

var randno = Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length)); //declare outside of the each to keep a single number
var cosas = $('.cosa1, .cosa2').each(function(i, cosa){    
    $(cosa).append(quotes[randno][i]); 
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
<div class="left-container">
  <div>
    <h1 class="cosa1"></h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right-container">
  <div>
    <h1 class="cosa2"></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need, anyway when I try to use it, nothing shows up: http://rough-cow.surge.sh/

Comment: You call the code inside the header (via an external file). On that time the document isn't loaded yet and the `cosa` containers probably aren't found. Try encapuslating the entire code with `$(function(){/*code here */})`. I've altered the example to include the same

Answer (score 0):

For the looks of your code you're using jQuery so let's go ahead and proceed.

First of all you need to encapsulate your code and to achieve that we'll use a multiple element selector:

```
// Initialize the constants (not literally because you really can't in JS).
var quotes = new Array('1', '2', '3');
var cosas = $('.cosa1, .cosa2');

// Then having control over all the elements you want to mannipulate
// just iterate through all of them and apply your @quotes math logic.
cosas.each(function(i, cosa){
    var randno = Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length));
    $(cosa).append(quotes[randno]);
});
```

Now basically what I did above is:

- Store in a variable multiple elements.
- Iterate this elements and append a number from the array.

You can check a working test here:
https://jsfiddle.net/5vez6yb6/

**UPDATE:**
**HTML**:

```
<div class="main-container">
<div class="left-container">
  <div>
    <h1 class="cosa1">Postres / </h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right-container">
  <div>
    <h1 class="cosa2">Hamburguesa / </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
// Initialize the constants (not literally because you really can't in JS).
var quotes = new Array('Perro', 'Pizza', 'Hamburguesa', 'Plátano', 'Postres');
var cosas = $('.cosa1, .cosa2');

var getRandomNumber = function()
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length));
}

// Then having control over all the elements you want to mannipulate
// just iterate through all of them and apply your @quotes math logic.
cosas.each(function(i, cosa){
    cosa = $(cosa);
    var found = false;
    var cosa_text = cosa.html();

    while (!found)
    {
      var randno = getRandomNumber();

      if (!cosa_text.includes(quotes[randno]))
      {
            cosa.append(quotes[randno]);

            found = true;
      }
    }
});
```

So basically I iterate inside the loop to find the text you will be appending without replicating it.

***Logic goes:***
While (Haven't found the word)
---Get a word and check if it's in the element.
---If it is not in the element, append the word and exit the while loop.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/5vez6yb6/3/

Comment: hey thanks! nothing shows up, edited question with html if that may be the issue :(

Comment: I made a mistake and confused .each()'s function's params:
It's not "function(cosa, i)" it is: "function(i, cosa)" (Difference between jQuery and MooTools).

Try it and let me know!

Comment: Tried again and still nothing [check it](http://clever-chickens.surge.sh)

Comment: Try going to the url I posted in the answer! It works there, so maybe there's something else going on? are you using jQuery?

Comment: Thank you very much man but I need to show specific combos, for instance i need to show burger/pizza - cake/muffin - soccer/football and so on, like this it is still randomized so sometimes pizza/pizza will show up.

Comment: I don't understand if your last sentence means I haven't solved your issue.
Do you need a different approach?

Comment: It does not solve my issue because sometimes michael/michael or chango/chango will show up, as said I have a specific list :(

Comment: Can you edit your question and add that information?
If you have a specific list you need a way to bind item1 to item2 -> 'item1/item2'…

Comment: I think I solved what you wanted to do…
Check the answer again I updated it and also here's the example working: https://jsfiddle.net/5vez6yb6/2/

Comment: I am sorry but you are not getting my question. I need to show only two words in the page PIZZA o HAMBURGER? on another page load PLATANO o MELOCOTON? With this logic they are still random and PLATANO o PLATANO? would show up...

Comment: I did, please check the answer and the JSFiddle. It appends a random word as long as it's not in the HTML.

If it's not that you should try re-formulating your question :)

Comment: in the HTML there's nothing as you can see in my question, as in there I only need to show a word from my list, nothing else. maybe different approach? :)